# Adding a new column in a temporary table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a temporary table in a PostgreSQL function and I want to insert a new `VARCHAR` column. It should have a value that depends on another column of the table, named "amount".

When the amount is positive I would like the value of the column row to be credit and when the value is negative the column should be debit.

I have one more request: I want to round the value of amount column in 2 decimal digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) followed by an `UPDATE`.

I initially said `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... USING` but that was wrong on two counts. `ADD COLUMN` takes a `DEFAULT` not `USING` - and You can't do it in one pass because neither a `DEFAULT` expression nor a `USING` expression may not refer to other columns.

So you must do:

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN colname varchar;
 UPDATE tablename SET colname = ( CASE WHEN othercol < 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Debit' END );
```

Think carefully about whether zero should be 'Debit' or 'Credit' and adjust the `CASE` accordingly.

For rounding, use [`round(amount,2)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html). There isn't enough detail in your question for me to be sure how; probably by `UPDATE`ing the temp table with `UPDATE thetable SET amount = round(amount,2)` but without the context it's hard to know if that's right. **That statement irreversibly throws information away** so it should only be used on a copy of the data.

Comment: I tried 'ALTER TABLE tmp_table ADD col1 varchar USING  (CASE WHEN SUM < 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Debit' END );' But there is a syntax error at or near "USING".
For rounding it said :'function round(double precision, integer) does not exist'

Comment: @user1392203 You're quite right. My mistake entirely. There were actually two errors: First, `ADD COLUMN` takes `DEFAULT` not `USING`; `USING` is for `ALTER COLUMN ... SET DATA TYPE`.  Second, neither `DEFAULT` nor `USING` may refer to other columns, so that was dead wrong. Updated.

Comment: @user1392203 As for `round()`, you didn't specify your table structure or types, so it wasn't possible to be exact. Running `\df round` in `psql` will show you the different `round()` functions. There you'll see that the form of `round` that takes a precision argument is `round(numeric,integer)`. So if you have a `double precision` argument you may have to cast it to `numeric` with `round(amount::numeric,2)`